# In Ocean's 8, which male con actors appear as cameo from the previous installments?

Tags: oceans-8, oceans-thirteen

*Ocean's 8* features some prominent cameos of real celebrities, but I also noticed that some of the characters from the "Danny Ocean"-Installments (Ocean's 11 through 13) are appearing on screen.

I am looking for information on which characters / actors appear and in what scene.

So far I found:

- Elliott Gould (aka Reuben): at the early cemetery scene
- Eddie Jemison (aka Livingston Dell) is Gary Randall at the hotel checkout scene (with "Monica")
- Matt Damon (aka Linus Caldwell) seems to be one of the undercover agents that detain Debbie

What more?

Comment: https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/movies/a21271889/oceans-8-cameos/

Comment: @Valorum Yes, I found this page too. However, aside from Shaobo Qin, which does not only have a cameo, but an actual role, all the others seem to be actual celebrities, not actors from the other movies.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but I found it interesting and worthy of a comment :-)

Comment: Matt Damon's cameo was cut from the movie: https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/06/oceans-8-matt-damon-carl-reiner-cameos-gary-ross. Same for Carl Reiner (Saul Bloom)